# Can I change Model User that used in auth system in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I tried to change User Model that used by default when use command    php artisan ui:auth
to another model 
but all of way to do that is not working 
What should to do that ?
I am using laravel version 7.x

Answer (score 2):

You can have different (or as many different) models as you want for various reasons.  You just need to change the relevant section in `config/auth.php`.  I always use a Models directory, so one of the first things I do with a new app is to relocate the User model and then tell Auth where to look for it:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

You also have to update the model's `use` statements in your controllers if you have custom logic, but for a vanilla Laravel Auth set-up, you should be good just by changing the config.

Edit: If you do have a structure like mine (a models directory) the default App\User namespace declaration has to change on the model itself:

Change:

```
namespace App;
```

To:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Or whatever it is that matches your structure.

Comment: I use vue auth set-up not vanilla
I do this but it's not work

Comment: @AddyDeveloper, make sure the namespaces match.  The default is ```App\User```; if you have it in Models, then the namespace for the model has to change to ```App\Models\User```, etc.  If you're using JWT or something, it's going to depend a bit on what your authentication workflow looks like, but at the end of it all, it still comes down to making sure the workflow is looking for the model in the correct place/namespace.

Comment: @AddyDeveloper, I edited to add an example of what to change on the model itself, if you need to do that, so your namespace declaration is correct.